# heroku is generating the same logs as development console but the same app in AWS is not generating the same logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am working on a Rails app which they are running in AWS EC2,

this app is coming from Heroku, and this app is in Heroku is generating the logs, all show like info and verbose in the console log

However, the same app running in the AWS ec2 is not generating the same logs report as in the heroku.

They are generated in the Console log but they are not saving all log in the cloud watch or log files in rails folder.

I assume it's a more RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT issue on EC2? as they are built by Heroku?

```
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
```

in the EC2 console log, this is perfect outcome log report and that what I'm looking for

[image]

but in Log report in log folder and cloudwatch show different report

[image]

Not sure where I am missing something even I have added this line and outcome still same

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = true
  config.log_level = :info 
  config.log_level = :debug
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed as I remove two items in the gem file

```
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'rails_stdout_logging'
```

as it generates all the verbose, info, debug into the log files at the log folder. and it show details in the cloudwatch